# Finding dependencies of containerized windows apps

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I would like to find out the missing dll needed for my exe file that is stored in the container. Found out https://stefanscherer.github.io/find-dependencies-in-windows-containers/ method but it requires installation of virtual machine.  Is it possible to install dependency walker into the container using docker file to find the missing dll? I am using windowservercore as base image.

Comment: Managed to solve the Issue.

Comment: How did you solve the issue???

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and ended up downloading [depends.exe](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) from the website and then copied the extracted files to a mounted location between my computer and the container.

Then I used depends.exe [from the command line](https://www.dependencywalker.com/help/html/hidr_command_line_help.htm) and was able to profile my app to find my missing late-loaded dependency without a GUI.

The `/c` option runs depends without opening the GUI.

This is the command line I used:
`depends.exe /c /f 1 /pg 1 /pl 1 /pf 1 /pb /of c:\build\profile.txt c:\build\source\path\to\executable-to-profile.exe`

The command prompt returned right away, making me feel like it did nothing, but I waited about 5 minutes or so and got a text file with the details.

I realize this is an old question, but I stumbled here during my search, so I thought maybe this would help someone.